# Vietnamese babel: font consistency

Tags: fonts, babel, mathpazo

I am writing a document in English, but want my name written in Vietnamese. I am using babel and mathpazo. The problem is that when I switch font to Vietnamese as in this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese,german,english]{babel}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\begin{document}
{\Large Vietnam}

\begin{otherlanguage}{vietnamese}
{\Large Việt Nam}
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

the font is also switched from Palatino to... something else, see the output below.

[image: Font switch in changing languages]

Is there anyway to keep the Palatino font also for Vietnamese language? I am very grateful to your comments.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you just want to write your name in Vietnamese? I would not change the language for that but tweak around this single case. I am sure we would be able to get that "e" in Palatino for you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but my name contains more complicated letters and I had to give up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text font defined by `mathpazo` is not available in T5 encoding (for Vietnamese). The Palatino clone in the TeX Gyre fonts is, so you can use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese,german,english]{babel}

\usepackage{mathpazo} % for math fonts
\usepackage{tgpagella} % overrides the text fonts in mathpazo

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
{\Large Vietnam}

\begin{otherlanguage}{vietnamese}
{\Large Việt Nam}
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

No oldstyle figures, I'm afraid.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, egreg. That's a great help! Just for my understanding: what are the oldstyle figures? (I did not see any of my figures affected.)

Comment: @ttuethao You had `\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}`, that would use oldstyle digits for numbers in text (not in math): see [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HGKXT.png)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I see that now. I was carefully distinguishing math numbers and text numbers, but that was perhaps overkill.