# Typesetting a single word with TeX Gyre Pagella at T5, using Palatino for everything else

Tags: xetex, babel, font-encodings

I need to typeset a single Vietnamese word in my otherwise English document. My document is in Palatino, which doesn't support T5, so after I switch to T5, it uses a different font. So far, this is the same problem as described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211665/2113). However, there the solution was to change the main font to TeX Gyre Pagella. I'd like to apply that solution **locally**, i.e. use TeX Gyre Pagella just for this one word.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1,T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[defaultsups]{newpxtext}
\usepackage[english,vietnamese]{babel}
\newfontfamily\vnfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}
Nguyen

\noindent

{\fontencoding{T5}\vnfont\selectfont{}Nguy\~\ecircumflex{}n}
\end{document}
```

However, this fails with:

> LaTeX Error: Command `\ecircumflex` unavailable in encoding `TU`.

If instead I write `\vnfont\fontencoding{T5}`, then the latter overrides the former and I get the non-Palatino-looking font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by getting rid of the `fontenc` red herring (which I only put in there on suggestion of the VnTeX documentation), and using UTF-8 directly with my choice of `\vnfont`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[defaultsups]{newpxtext}
\newfontfamily\vnfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}
Nguyen, \vnfont Nguyễn, \normalfont and Nguyen.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you are loading `fontspec`, I presume you are using either `xelatex` or `lualatex`. In such a case, don’t load `fontenc` and declare the font for `vietnamese` in the following way:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\babelfont[vietnamese]{rm}{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}

Nguyen in English text.

\foreignlanguage{vietnamese}{Nguy\~{\^{e}}n}

% Better:
\foreignlanguage{vietnamese}{Nguyễn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a full self-contained example that also uses Palatino for the non-Vietnamese parts? If I take yours, and add `\usepackage[defaultsups]{newpxtext}`, the 'Nguyen in English text' line isn't typeset in Palatino.

Comment: @Cactus Sadly, `newpxtext` assumes `pdftex` and loads `fontenc` with `T1` as default. Overcoming this problem would be more complicated than you own solution.

Comment: hmm, so what's the recommended way of loading Palatino into Xetex?